What happens to the data when entity- and time-fixed effects are applied?
Let us assume that the true data generating process is as follows:
Y_it = beta_0 + beta_1 X_it + u_it

What happens exactly when I apply both entity- and time-fixed effects?
(Y_it - Y_i - Y_t) = beta_0 + beta_1 (X_it - X_i - X_t) + (u_it - u_i - u_t)

where Y_i = mean of all Y-values for entity i and Y_t = mean of all Y-values across entities for time t.
Is this what really happens to the data?
Here it's a simple example for illustrational purposes:
Let's imagine the original data set looks like this:
t t+1 t+2
A 10 20 30
B 20 30 40
C 30 40 50
The countries mean are:
A 20
B 30
C 40
Subtracting those countries means from the original values we get:
**t**    **t+1**    **t+2**  

A -10 0 10
B -10 0 10
C -10 0 10
The year means are (for the already transformed data):
t -10
t+1 0
t+2 10
Subtracting these years means from the transformed values we get:
**t**    **t+1**    **t+2**  

A 0 0 10
B 0 0 10
C 0 0 10
Hence, I would say that the value for the transformed data after applying country and year-fixed effects is, for instance, for the very first value at the top links is: Y_it - Y_i - Y_t = 10 - 20 - (-10) = 0.

I am not sure what you mean by "Is this what really happens to the data?"  Nor do I understand the construction of your second expression:  the mean value of (Y_it - Y_i - Y_t) will be the negative of the mean value of Y_it and similarly for the other terms so beta_0 estimate for the second expression is unlikely to be close to the beta_0 in the first expression even in sign.

... including entity and time effects just acts as demeaning the data along the time and entities.

@Math-fun Thanks for your comment. So, I think you're confirming my second equation, right?

... You are ritgh, though note that $\beta_0$ drops, as well as all variables which are only time-varying or only vary across entities.

But $(Y_{it} - Y_{i} - Y_{t})$ does not just demean the data along the time and entities - it over-demeans.  You would want $(Y_{it} - Y_{i} - Y_{t} +Y)$ where $Y$ is the overall mean, and similarly for $X$ and perhaps $u$;  only then would $\beta_0$ disappear

@Henry I've edited my question by adding a simple example and I think you're wrong.

But that is not what I thought you originally said.  Your example says $Y_t$ would be $-10,0,10$ when from your starting data it would have been the column averages of $20, 30, 40$.  The constant difference of $30,30,30$ is in fact the average of your original data, precisely the point I was trying (and apparently failing) to make

@Henry Thanks for commenting again. Yes, I understood what you were saying now. You're actually right!
